# Why can I not install pyenv?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, pyenv

**Problem:**

I am using python 2.7 on my Windows 10 computer.

When I run

```
pip install pyenv
```

I get the error shown below.

This is the only pip module that I have run into that I cannot install successfully. I'm not sure why this happens. Any ideas?

**Error Message:**

```
pip install pyenv
Collecting pyenv
  Downloading pyenv-20150113.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pyenv
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyenv: started

  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyenv: finished with status 'error'
  Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\u                                               sers\\user\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-_6j2tq\\pyenv\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open                                               )(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_w                                               heel -d c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\tmprb9n7epip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  installing to build\bdist.win32\wheel
  running install
  Cloning into 'C:/Users/user/.pyenv'...
  Cloning into 'C:/Users/user/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-doctor'...
  Cloning into 'C:/Users/user/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-installer'...
  Cloning into 'C:/Users/user/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-pip-rehash'...
  Cloning into 'C:/Users/user/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-update'...
  Cloning into 'C:/Users/user/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv'...
  Cloning into 'C:/Users/user/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-which-ext'...

  WARNING: seems you still have not added 'pyenv' to the load path.

  # Load pyenv automatically by adding
  # the following to your profile:

  export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
  eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-_6j2tq\pyenv\setup.py", line 33, in <module>
      cmdclass=dict(install=PyenvInstall),
    File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 257, in run
      self.distinfo_dir)
    File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 393, in egg2dist
      raise ValueError(err)
  ValueError: Egg metadata expected at build\bdist.win32\wheel\.\pyenv-20150113.1-py2.7.egg-info but not                                                found

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pyenv
  Running setup.py clean for pyenv
Failed to build pyenv
Installing collected packages: pyenv
  Running setup.py install for pyenv: started
    Running setup.py install for pyenv: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\                                               \users\\user\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-_6j2tq\\pyenv\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', op                                               en)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" insta                                               ll --record c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-wjwco5-record\install-record.txt --single-version-ex                                               ternally-managed --compile:
    usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
       or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
       or: -c --help-commands
       or: -c cmd --help

    error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\user\\appdata                                               \\local\\temp\\pip-build-_6j2tq\\pyenv\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.rea                                               d().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\mse                                               dmon\appdata\local\temp\pip-wjwco5-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compi                                               le" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-_6j2tq\pyenv\
```

Comment: `pip install pyenv` is not for windows. It supports mac and linux. [link](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/62)

Comment: In recent days we developed pyenv for windows called [pyenv-win](https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win). `pip install pyenv-win`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "pypi" [page of pyvenv](https://pypi.org/project/pyenv/) mentions:

> The PyPi support is not tested by many users yet, so the direct way
>   ist still recommended if you want to play it safe.

The authors of the package recommend to use their dedicated [installation script](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer/blob/master/bin/pyenv-installer).

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks for the feedback.